# Convert json string to list object (Index number of json object affects the convertion)

Tags: c#, json

Please take a look at the photo.

i am having difficulty trying to convert JSON string to list object.
After troubleshooting, i found out that the problem is due to the Json index(Number is jumbling up and not in order 1,2,4,5,6,5601,5611 ..). Anyone idea how i can convert the json into object in an ascending order list 12345678910.. (model[0], model[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE7zT.png), model[2], model[3] ....)

```
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            jsonstr = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
        };

        List<Notification> model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Notification>>(jsonstr, settings).Where(m => m != null).ToList();
```

[image]

Error message:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path '1', line 1, position 5.'

JSON RESULT

```
{"1":{"confirmation_status":"Rejected","createDateTime":"2018-08-31 16:58:58.087","logID":1,"notification_message":"\"There is a change request for \"Vital\" to be approved.\"","read_status":"true","recipient":"68d9dffc-b3be-4527-a89a-829b76abf754","sender":"01a94cf4-5df4-4097-b6ea-d929170de1e7","senderDetails":"Adeline Tan "},"6":{"confirmation_status":"Rejected","createDateTime":"2018-08-31 16:58:58.087","logID":6,"notification_message":"\"There is a change request for \"Vital\" to be approved.\"","read_status":"true","recipient":"68d9dffc-b3be-4527-a89a-829b76abf754","sender":"01a94cf4-5df4-4097-b6ea-d929170de1e7","senderDetails":"Adeline Tan "},"5601":{"confirmation_status":"Pending","createDateTime":"2018-08-31 16:58:58.087","logID":5601,"notification_message":"\"There is a change request for \"Vital\" to be approved.\"","read_status":"true","recipient":"68d9dffc-b3be-4527-a89a-829b76abf754","sender":"01a94cf4-5df4-4097-b6ea-d929170de1e7","senderDetails":"Adeline Tan "},"5611":{"confirmation_status":"Pending","createDateTime":"2018-08-31 16:58:58.087","logID":5611,"notification_message":"\"There is a change request for \"Vital\" to be approved.\"","read_status":"true","recipient":"68d9dffc-b3be-4527-a89a-829b76abf754","sender":"01a94cf4-5df4-4097-b6ea-d929170de1e7","senderDetails":"Adeline Tan "}}
```

Notification Class:

```
 public class Notification
{
    public string confirmation_status { get; set; }
    public string createDateTime { get; set; }
    public int logID { get; set; }
    public string notification_message { get; set; }
    public string read_status { get; set; }
    public string recipient { get; set; }
    public string sender {get; set; }
    public string senderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us you json data?

Comment: show us your JSON. Error message says that you trying to convert single object to list

Comment: Also show Notification class

Comment: The shown JSON is an object and not an array

Comment: thank you guys for your help. I added the json data and notification as requested.

Answer (score 2):

The shown JSON is an object and not an array

most likely you want this

```
List<Notification> model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionay<string,Notification>>(jsonstr, settings)
.Select(kvp => kvp.Value)    
.Where(m => m != null)
.OrderBy(m => m.logID)
.ToList();
```

Where the JSON is converted to a dictionary and the values extracted to the desired type.